# How can I transfer database objects from a local database in App_Data Folder in a VS 2008 web app project to an SQL Server 2000 database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, dts

We have a VS 2008 web application project under development for which a local database (mdf file) was created in its **App_Data** folder. Now we have changed our plans and decided to use a SQL Server 2000 Database instead of the file database in App_Data.

To achieve this, I want to use DTS Import/Export wizard to move the local database objects to an SQL Server 2000 database in a remote server. However, I am not sure on how to refer to the local App_Data database in the **"Choose a Data Source"** screen of the DTS wizard. 
In this screen, what type of **Data Source** do I pick and how can I refer to the local database in App_Data Folder?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That's a SQL Server Express database - you can connect to it using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 comes with the SQL Publishing Wizard. You can script objects and data to a file and then run against the other service. I think it's under the Right Mouse Click options in the Server Explorer.

I can't be more exact at the moment because VS 2008 is currently installing /: